# Spring Rest Template Json output mapping to Object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

When i make the API call using Spring Rest template, getting Json response like below

```
[
  {
    "Employee Name": "xyz123",       
    "Employee Id": "12345"
  }
]
```

I was created object to map the json response like below:

```
public class Test {
    
    @JsonProperty("Employee Name")
    private String employeeName;
    
    @JsonProperty("Employee Id")
    private String employeeId;

}
```

But I am getting below error when i make rest api call:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.pojo.Emp` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:
> Cannot deserialize instance of `com.pojo.Emp` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1

How to map the Rest template Json response to object when Json has spaces in parameter keys?

Comment: Can you show how you call rest API using Rest Template ?

Comment: ResponseEntity<Emp> resp = restTemplate.exchange(endpointUrl,HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity,EmpApp.class);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON response is an array of object since it's wrapped in `[]`, so map the data into a `List<Emp>`. Here used `ParameterizedTypeReference` to create the TypeReference of `List<Emp>`

```
ResponseEntity<List<Emp>> response = restTemplate.exchange(endpointUrl, 
                                                  HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity,
                                             new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Emp>>(){}); 
List<Emp> employees = response.getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to map array to object. You can do something like this

```
ResponseEntity<Test[]> response =
  restTemplate.getForEntity(
  url,
  Test[].class);
Test[] employees = response.getBody();
```

For more information check [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj,Your response helps me understand the ways of handling list obj with rest template